# c++ friend template function errors

Tags: c++, gcc

I can compile the following code with gcc 6.5. However, it can't pass the compilation of gcc 5.5. Could anyone share me some workaround?

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
class Future;
template<typename T, template<typename> class FutureType = Future>
std::shared_ptr<FutureType<T>> MakeReadyFuture(T&& v);

template<typename T>
class Future {
protected:
    template<typename O, template<typename> class FutureType>
    std::shared_ptr<FutureType<O>> friend MakeReadyFuture(O&& v);

    Future(T& v) {}
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class FutureType>
std::shared_ptr<FutureType<T>> MakeReadyFuture(T&& v) {
    return std::shared_ptr<FutureType<T>>(new FutureType<T>(v));
}

int main() {
    MakeReadyFuture(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> 21:5: error: 'Future::Future(T&) [with T = int]' is protected

It can be tested on https://godbolt.org/z/ZXlHK1

Comment: Looks like a bug as it works on all versions of Clang and GCC  6.5 onwards. Not possible to upgrade the compiler?

Comment: @P.W I think it's a compiler's bug too. And the installed gcc on my machine is 6.5. I got this error because someone in my team uses gcc 5.5.

Comment: [OT] better to reverse template parameter to allow to to provide `FutureType` easily.

Comment: [passkey-idiom/](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) might be used to allow to use `std::make_shared`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug of GCC. Here is my workaround which compiled on GCC 5.5:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
class Future;

struct FutureCreator{
    template<typename T, template<typename> class FutureType = Future>
    static std::shared_ptr<FutureType<T>> MakeReadyFuture(T&& v) {
        return std::shared_ptr<FutureType<T>>(new FutureType<T>(v));
    }
};


template<typename T>
class Future {
protected:
    friend FutureCreator;

    Future(T& v) {}
};


int main() {
    FutureCreator::MakeReadyFuture(1);
    return 0;
}
```